# resize lightning component in community builder - locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service, community-builder

I have issue with resize component in community builder. 
Currently I added to init window.addEventListener but I know - LOCKER SERVICE:

controller:

```
     doinit : function(component) {

                var action = component.get("c.serverEcho");
                action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                    var state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {

                    console.log('response', response.getReturnValue());

                }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors) {
                        if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                            console.log("Error message: " + 
                                     errors[0].message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown error");
                    }
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);

            component.set('v.resizeCallback', $A.getCallback(function(){
                if(component.isValid()) {
                    helper.helperMethod(component, event, helper);
                }
            }));
            window.addEventListener('resize', component.get('v.resizeCallback')); 
        }
```

but in Community I can't use window etc -> I have exception in helper.helperMethod:

Error:

> Error: ->>>>  TypeError: component1.getElement is not a function
>    at Object.scrollArrowsState (DTE_MainMenu.js:636)
>    at eval (DTE_MainMenu.js:38)
>    at callbackWrapper (aura_proddebug.js:26148)
>    at nrWrapper (?app=commeditor&view=editor&viewid=278adb0d-f4af-44b4-bffa-21d80fd59041&formFactor=DESKTOP&language=en_CA:3)

I have problem in 2 line in helper:

```
helperMethod : function(component, event, helper) {
    var component1 = component.find('comp1');
    var comp1Scroll = component1.getElement().scrollWidth; //problem
    console.log('scrollWidth', comp1Scroll);
}
```

In this concept I tried consol log with properly value every time when I resize component

Comment: A little more code would help further. your markup would help it further .

Comment: I a litle corrected special for you. But I can't copy paste only concept.

Comment: Best guess would be that "component" and "component1" are components from different namespaces. So component1 is a SecureComponentRef and will prevent component from accessing its dom elements. You cannot reach into the internals of a component from another namespace.

Comment: if I use <div> or <aura:html tag="div"> I have problem because this is in different namespace ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine in the test below:

**testResize.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <h1>Test Resize Callback</h1>
    <div aura:id="comp1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ...
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

**testResizeController.js**

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', $A.getCallback(function(){
            if(component.isValid()) {
                helper.helperMethod(component, event, helper);
            }
        }));        
    }
})
```

**testResizeHelper.js**

```
({
    helperMethod : function(component) {
        var component1 = component.find('comp1');
        var comp1Scroll = component1.getElement().scrollWidth; //problem
        console.log('scrollWidth', comp1Scroll);
    }
})
```

There is no need to add the component attribute, but it still works with it:

**testResize.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="resizeCallback" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <h1>Test Resize Callback</h1>
    <div aura:id="comp1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ...
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

**testResizeController.js**

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.resizeCallback', $A.getCallback(function(){
            if(component.isValid()) {
                helper.helperMethod(component, event, helper);
            }
        }));
        window.addEventListener('resize', component.get('v.resizeCallback')); 
    }
})
```

The problem is most likely with the aura:id on your target element.